# IBM MFP 8 - Create dynamic web page in adapter

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

We have a requirement to push one web page dynamically from the adapter. I had gone through IBM MFP 8 architecture and even other websites also. I didn't find any solution.

Is there any provision IBM MFP 8 is giving to create a dynamic webpage in the adapter where we can give CSS and even we can add click listeners?

Comment: Where will the web page be rendered ?

Comment: Inside ionic3-cordova mobile application